# Why doesn't the Grails findOrSaveBy* dynamic finder accept a second parameter for creation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, grails, dynamic, grails-2.0

Coming from a Rails background I was happy to see that Grails 2.0.x supports the dynamic finders of the form `Model.findOrSaveBy*` and `Model.findOrCreateBy*`. However, the functionality is extremely artificially limited -- according to the [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/ref/Domain%20Classes/findOrSaveBy.html), the method accepts *n* parameters, where *n* is the exact number of attributes listed in the method call. So for example:

```
class Car {
  String color
  String license

  static constraints = {
    license blank: false, unique: true
    color blank: false, inList: ["red", "black"]
  }
}

/* If there exists a Car(color: red, license: "ABCDEF") */

// WORKS
Car.findOrSaveByColor("red")  // will find the car
Car.findOrSaveByLicense("ABCDEF")  // will find the car
Car.findOrSaveByLicenseAndColor("UVWXYZ", "black")  // will persist a new car

// DOES NOT WORK
Car.findOrSaveByLicense("UVWXYZ")  // will fail because the color is not provided
Car.findOrSaveByLicense("UVWXYZ", color: "black")  // will fail due to an extra parameter
Car.findOrSaveByLicenseAndColor("ABCDEF", "black")  // will fail due to persisting a new instance because the color does not match, which then has a unique collision
```

I only care about locating via the unique `license` value, but if the object does not exist, I need to populate it with all required attributes. [Rails allows you to do this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html) via a `Hash` parameter, as follows:

```
// Using findOrSaveBy* because Grails:"save"::Rails:"create" and "create" does not persist in Grails
Car.findOrSaveByLicense("ABCDEF", color: "red")  // will find a car with that license plate regardless of color or persist a new entry with the license and color "red"
```

Is there a reason this functionality was not implemented in Grails? It seems to me this greatly limits the usefulness of these dynamic finders. I guess I could add a `methodMissing` to the domain classes which intercepts the call and delegates to something like:

```
def car = Car.findByLicense("UVWXYZ") ?: new Car(license: "UVWXYZ", color: "red").save(flush: true)
```

but it just seems very repetitive. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your example, an easy solution would be giving a default value to color in your domain class:

```
class Car {
  String color = "red"
  String license

  static constraints = {
    license blank: false, unique: true
    color blank: false, inList: ["red", "black"]
  }
}
```

Then the following should work:

```
Car.findOrSaveByLicense("UVWXYZ")
```

Comment: That works if there is logically a default value for the unspecified attributes (and perhaps the example oversimplified the scenario), but in most cases that doesn't work because there are values in scope wherever `.findOrSaveBy*` is being called but not at class definition time.